# To find out the value of $a$ from the given infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I am given with the following infinite series $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a^{\frac{m(m-1)}{2}} \rho^m \bigg[ A - k \frac{m(m-1)}{2}\bigg] = 0$$ where $0<a<1$, $A$ is a fixed positive quantity. Further $0 < \rho < 1$.

I have to find out the value of $a$.

Hint is also given which is : Obtain the value of $a$ for a fixed $\rho$ by an iterative procedure.

I have no idea how to find out this. Plz help me.

Comment: Could you say what is $k$?

Comment: $k$ is a fixed positive integer.